# How can I achieve this header layout?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am trying to implement the following header design in Bootstrap.

[image]

I tried using the grid system but this does not feel like it should be the way to go. The code I have so far does not place the 2 buttons in the right lower corner in the correct position.

The HTML:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-12 mb-3">
    <div class="line"></div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-3 pt-4 pl-5">
        <img src="logo.png" class="logo" />
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-5"></div>
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <a class="btn btn-primary" href="#" role="button">choice 1</a>
        <a class="btn btn-primary" href="#" role="button">choice 2</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
.line {
  position: relative;
}

.line::after {
  content: "";
  background-color: #ed1e79;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 20px;
  top: 90px;
  left: 0px;
  z-index: -1;
}

.btn {
  border-radius: 0 !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `line` shouldn't be an element in your markup. It should be a background image or a pseudo-element on an existing container element. You can then use Bootstrap's flex structure and align the two buttons vertically at the end of the column.

```css
.bg-line {
    background-image: linear-gradient(180deg,
            transparent calc(50% - 6px),
            #ff0000 calc(50% - 6px),
            #ff0000 calc(50% + 6px),
            #ffffff calc(50% + 6px));
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" 
  href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.css"/>

<div class="bg-line d-flex justify-content-between align-items-end">
    <div class="col"><!-- flexes to fill space -->
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/90" class="logo" />
    </div>

    <div class="col-auto btn-group"><!-- shrinks to fit content -->
        <a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" href="#" role="button">choice 1</a>
        <a class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm" href="#" role="button">choice 2</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

**[Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/kfrts25q/)**

Answer (score 0):

using flex - `d-flex`, align-items - `align-items-end` and justify-content - `justify-content-between` it should work.

example in CSS:

```css
header {
  margin: 10px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  border: solid 2px black;
  padding: 10px;
  align-items: flex-end;
}

.img {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border: solid 2px black;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.btns {
  height: 20px;
  width: 150px;
  border: solid 2px black;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="img"></div>
  <div class="btns"></div>
</header>
```

Comment: Ideally you'd implement Bootstrap classes instead of all that custom CSS.

Comment: everything I wrote in custom CSS I wrote the equivalent class in bootstrap